# Font size macro only works once in the document

Tags: macros, fontsize

I am writing a paper where HI comes up a lot. I need the capitalized "I" to be slightly smaller than the "H" so I have been doing this: H\small{I}

However this only works in the first instance of my document, all the other instances seem to ignore the \small macro and capitalize both letters the same way. Anyone else run into that?

Thanks!

Lorraine

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

`\small` is a font switch - it does not take an argument. It makes everything afterwards small until it is cancelled by another size command or the document or group ends.

Try

```
H{\small I}
```

The `{}` will limit the effects of the switch to just what is contained within them. (They make a group.)

Comment: Indeed! I have been staring at my computer so long I didn't see all the rest was smaller font after that… Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably a better solution is using small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\Hi{\textsc{Hi}}

And now you can write \Hi\ and \large\Hi\ and \Large\Hi\ and \LARGE\Hi \ and \huge\Hi\ and \Huge\Hi.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Przemysław Scherwentke has already given an arguably better answer (both in looks and because it scales well), but in case you wanted exactly that size difference between the two characters, `\newcommand{\HI}{H{\small I}\ }` will allow you to insert that anywhere with just `\HI`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\HI}{H{\small I}\ }

\begin{document}
    This should work, \HI wherever \HI you need it \HI to.
\end{document}
```

Comment: except that if it's immediately followed by punctuation, there will be a space between `\HI` and the punctuation.  better to use `\xspace` from the `xspace` package.

Comment: @barbrabeeton I didn't think of that, thanks.